# Simple loading test for my web app

Tags: web-applications, load-testing

We're interesting to run a simple and basic loading tests to our new-born web app, not too complicates- login or navigation in the site is not necessary- just bomb our web with many concurrence get requests to a predefined list of URLs.

I was looking on [apache ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) and [siege](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/), and it looks really great- just a couple of minutes to set up and I got many get requests to my sites, the problem with those platform is that when I define a "GET" request to some page it just hit this page and never request it's inner resources (images, css and js), of course I can add those resources to the url list but it won't give me a real results (#rpm and all).

any suggest what can I do?
can I do what I want with apache ab or siege?
do you know a similar tool that let me doing it? I looked over JMeter it's look like a bit overkill.

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using [httperf](http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/linux/httperf/).
Although it has many bugs that crush the process with lots of segmentation faults, it has nice feature that let you use sessions (--wsesslog).

Another option is to use siege to simulate one client and run couple of clients in parallel:
lets say you have a url.txt that contains all the url that you want to test and a resources.txt file that contains a generic resources that each file import (images, css and js), so you can use this script to simulate number of clients in parallel:

```
#run X users in parallel:
i=1; 
for line in $(head -|NUMBER OF CLIENTS| urls.txt); do 
    echo $line > client$i;
    cat resources.txt >> client$i;
    let "i += 1";
done;

for f in $(ls client*); do 
    siege -c |NUMBER OF CALLS| -r 100 -f $f -b &
done;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you try a tool that allows you to record a session in your browser. These tools will generally capture all the resources on each page and include them in the test.  A search for "load testing software" will reveal many options. I'll put in a plug for the free version of our product ([Load Tester LITE](http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/free-load-tester-lite.html)), which should work well for the scenarios you have described and will allow you to test with an unlimited number of users.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the answer: the Siege FAQ gives you [two options](http://www.joedog.org/siege-faq/#a21); both are straightforward-ish.

In your comment, you write that "Siege treats each URL separately" - that's not just, Siege, that's how your browser works. It starts by downloading an HTML file, and within that HTML file it will see links to other assets (images, javascript files etc.) and will download those. By using sproxy, you can re-create see what your browser is doing, and save that as instructions for Siege.

Secondly, a suggestion - use [Bad Boy](http://www.badboy.com.au/) with JMeter; that way, you can click around on your website, and capture the downloads, then re-play using JMeter.

Thirdly, a note of caution - by downloading all the images, links etc. you are effectively testing the performance of your webserver (Apache, IIS, whatever), not the performance of your web app. Even the most hardened cynic probably accepts that your webserver's performance has already been established by others, and is almost certainly not going to be a problem. Do you really want to test this?

Comment: I wan't to see how many users can access my site simultaneously, therefore I want statistics on all resources in one page as one piece- because this what represent single user for me. therefore Siege answer (1) not helping me, because it threat each url separately and that's why I'm testing static resources (3)

Comment: After your comment- yes, I absolutely understand this, but again- my goal is to see how many users can enter my home page simultaneously, in other words- how many users can access the page and all its resources